# Redundant : enter user id again for forgot password

Tags: usability, forms, password-reminder

Many a times, I use forgot password link after trying a password that I think is correct but doesn't work. In other words I have already provided my userid/email address.

[image]

Since the password is incorrect I am shown an error page

[image]

On this page, my login ID is pre-filled. So far so good.

Now, I realized that I have forgotten my password and I need to reset it. 
So I clicked "forgotten my password"

[image]

In most of the sites, I have to enter my email id/ user id again.

Is there any logic behind this?

Comment: My guess is that they're just simply too far away from each other as far as use cases go. Some might go straight to 'Find your account'. I think it's the gap between the two that is the cause though.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the reason is that they **want** you to retype your e-mail address so you definitly don't make any typos this time, to get you out of auto-pilot.

Another thing, again, refers to the auto-pilot in you, is to use that action as a double confirmation that you, in fact, want to perform that action.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have shown, **the "find your account" page is asking for different information than the login page.**

- The log in just asks for your email address or phone number.
- The "forgot password" feature allows you to enter email address, phone number, name, or user name.

The reason for this is that maybe the user who reaches this point has forgotten what email address or phone number is associated with their account.  Therefore, they are directed through a search and verify process to help identify their account before moving to the next step of sending a password.

Perhaps you could argue that most people know their email and just need the password, so this should be pre-populated as a starting point.  However,

- Not doing so emphasizes the intended workflow here: users need to stop and ensure that they have the correct account, not just click through (as Xabre points out).
- The "forgot password" feature is very infrequently used, so it is hardly harmful to require typing the email address again.